How to fetch transaction data of Safe Wallet on Arbitrum
I would like to fetch transaction data of the Gnosis Safe wallet on Arbitum L2 chain.
I have found the following answer for mainnet:
https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40822-export-transaction-data
The recommendation was to fetch it the following way:
https://safe-transaction-mainnet.safe.global/api/v1/safes/0xA063Cb7CFd8E57c30c788A0572CBbf2129ae56B6/multisig-transactions/
However, when I tried to change the URL from mainnet.safe.glabal to arbitrum.safe.global, it does not work for me.
How can I change the following URL to fetch all the transactions on Arbitrum:
https://safe-transaction-arbitrum.safe.global/api/v1/safes/0xc6a19210a6c026121f1f552634804c1a719caf77/multisig-transactions/
Thank you in advance!

The service works as intended for arbitrum: https://safe-transaction-arbitrum.safe.global/api/v1/safes/0xA063Cb7CFd8E57c30c788A0572CBbf2129ae56B6/multisig-transactions/
However it seems that the address you tried to input (0xc6a19210a6c026121f1f552634804c1a719caf77) is not recognized, neither on Arbitrum nor on mainnet. Can you double check to make sure you entered the correct address?
Thanks in advance; Best, Louis

I can confirm that the address is correct. The address mentioned above can be found in Arbiscan and debank.
What should I do to fix the issue for the address to be also recognized on Safe to fetch transactions?
Thank you! Tim

Can you please try again with this address? 0xc6a19210a6c026121F1f552634804C1a719cAf77 It is the same address but checksummed using ethsum.netlify.app. It should work now! https://safe-transaction-arbitrum.safe.global/api/v1/safes/0xc6a19210a6c026121F1f552634804C1a719cAf77/multisig-transactions/ Best, Louis

It works. Thanks a lot!

I can now see all the transactions and transaction info, however, the transaction amounts are incorrect. How can I fetch the correct transaction amounts using Gnosis Safe API? Thank you!
